# Replacing argument 'props' with variable names doesn't work in Reactjs functional syntax with webpack 1

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I'm following a tutorial from Lynda for ReactJs which is based on Webpack 1.

If I replace this:

```
import 'path/to/style.scss'

export const MyValues = (props) => (
  <div className="values">
    <div className="value-one">
      <span>{props.one}</span>
    </div>
    <div className="value-two">
      <span>{props.two}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

to this:

```
import 'path/to/style.scss'

export const MyValues = (one, two) => (
  <div className="values">
    <div className="value-one">
      <span>{one}</span>
    </div>
    <div className="value-two">
      <span>{two}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

(changing argument 'props' to arguments 'one' and 'two' and calling the variables directly later)

it compiles but the screen is blank. I don't know what the problem really is. Is it a problem with the syntax, or is it Webpack 1 problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do it this way because props is an object

```
 import 'path/to/style.scss'

export const MyValues = ({one, two}) => (
  <div className="values">
    <div className="value-one">
      <span>{one}</span>
    </div>
    <div className="value-two">
      <span>{two}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Oh, so I'll need to enclose it in curlys ? Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to destructre you props to extract `one` and `two` arguments from them

Enclose them within `{}` like

```
import 'path/to/style.scss'

export const MyValues = ({one, two}) => (
  <div className="values">
    <div className="value-one">
      <span>{one}</span>
    </div>
    <div className="value-two">
      <span>{two}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

So what actually happens with  the above method if that if you are passing props like

```
<MyValues one="1" two="2" three="3" four="4"/>
```

And if you only want to use props `one`, `two` then {one, two} will make them available from props and you can use it like `{one}` and `{two}`